# Prestashop 1.7 Payment module

Tags: php, prestashop

I am creating a credit card payment module for prestashop 1.7

I don't know how to send my post values on an external url and receive its response if the transaction is success or failed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make things like this :

- Make a module (https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) and extend
  it with PaymentModule, not just Module.
- Register interesting hooks (http://build.prestashop.com/news/module-development-changes-in-17/) and make a function like this in your module :

  ```
   public function hookHookName($params) {
     // Do things here
   }
  ```
- Play with this Hook specially (first part is hook name and second are $params)  :

  ```
  Hook::exec('actionValidateOrder', array(
     'cart' => $this->context->cart,
     'order' => $order,
     'customer' => $this->context->customer,
     'currency' => $this->context->currency,
     'orderStatus' => $order_status
  ));
  ```
- Make calls (curl / file_get_contents for instance) on that moment before validating anything.
- A good way to know how to do it could be to download Paypal Module (it's free) and see how they did it.